# Consultation about focus in EditText in Dialog

Tags: java, android

i try to get focus on EditText that i have in Dialog

in the main form:

```
data myDialog = new data(context, "MyDialog", new OnReadyListener());
myDialog.show();
```

in the Dialog:

```
public EditText CC;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.data);
        CC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
        CC.requestFocus();
```

and in the xml file i put this:

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtQty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
             >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```

but i dont get focus on my EditText, why ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `data` is a subclass of `Dialog`. In that case, try requesting focus on your `EditText` after the dialog is shown.

For example, you could try overriding the `show()` method, with an implementation like this:

```
@Override
public void show()
{
    super.show();
    CC.requestFocus();
}
```